# Swift: How to know if an instance needs to be copied?

Tags: swift, memory-management

In each of the examples below, does `blob.0` or `text` need to be copied? How do you know?

#### Setup

```
import SQLite3
private let static_destructor = unsafeBitCast(0, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
private let transient_destructor = unsafeBitCast(-1, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
```

#### Examples

1. `bind_blob`

   ```
   func bind_blob(_ stmt: OpaquePointer, _ blob: (UnsafeRawPointer, Int32)) {
     sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 1, blob.0, blob.1, transient_destructor)
   }
   ```
2. `bind_blobs`

   ```
   func bind_blobs(_ stmt: OpaquePointer, _ blobs: [(UnsafeRawPointer, Int32)]) {
     for (index, blob) in blobs.enumerated() {
       sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, Int32(index+1), blob.0, blob.1, transient_destructor)
     }
   }
   ```
3. `bind_text`

   ```
   func bind_text(_ stmt: OpaquePointer, _ text: String) {
     sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, text, -1, transient_destructor)
   }
   ```
4. `bind_texts`

   ```
   func bind_texts(_ stmt: OpaquePointer, _ texts: [String]) {
     for (index, text) in texts.enumerated() {
       sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, Int32(index+1), text, -1, transient_destructor)
     }
   }
   ```

Ie, should I use `static_destructor` instead of `transient_destructor` in any of the examples?

Related question: [When to use SQLITE_TRANSIENT vs SQLITE_STATIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229102/when-to-use-sqlite-transient-vs-sqlite-static)

Comment: Instead of describing code, could you edit your question to include actual code?

Comment: @robmayoff sure. Done. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `bind_text` and `bind_texts` functions, you need to use the transient destructor. When you pass a Swift `String` to a C function as a `const char *` argument, Swift does not guarantee that the pointer will remain valid after the C function returns. The [Calling Functions With Pointer Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/manual_memory_management/calling_functions_with_pointer_parameters) article says this:

> The pointer you pass to the function is only guaranteed to be valid for the duration of the function call. Do not persist the pointer and access it after the function has returned.

In your `bind_blob` and `bind_blobs` functions, it depends where the `UnsafeRawPointer` comes from and when you execute the SQL statement. If you're getting the pointer using any sort of Swift `withUnsafeWhatever` function, then the pointer is not valid after the `withUnsafeWhatever` function returns. For example, the [`withUnsafeBytes(of:_:)` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2998148-withunsafebytes) says this:

> The buffer pointer argument is valid only for the duration of the closure’s execution.

If you bind your blob, execute the statement, and then no longer use the binding, then you can use the static destructor. This is okay with the static destructor:

```
let data: Data = ...
data.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in
    if let pointer = rawBuffer.baseAddress {
        bind_blob(statement, (pointer, rawBuffer.count))
        execute(statement)
        // No more use of statement unless the parameter is rebound.
    }
}
```

But this is not okay with the static destructor:

```
let data: Data = ...
data.withUnsafeBytes { rawBuffer in
    if let pointer = rawBuffer.baseAddress {
        bind_blob(statement, (pointer, rawBuffer.count))
    }
}
execute(statement)
```

Comment: Thank you! What a beautiful answer. I appreciate you for providing links to and quoting the relevant documentation and for providing clear explanations and elaborating with code examples. And yes, I am using `withUnsafeBytes`. One follow-up question: How do I know when SQLite is finished with the blob or string?

Comment: SQLite is finished with it when you stop using the `sqlite3_stmt` to which it is bound.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I figured it'd be finished with the blob or string after the first call to `sqlite3_step()`, or after calling`sqlite3_bind_*()` again with a different value for the same parameter (which I'm not sure is even allowed), or after calling `sqlite3_clear_bindings()`.

Comment: Well, yes, if you overwrite the binding with another call to `sqlite3_bind_*`, or clear it with `sqlite3_clear_bindings`, then SQLite will also be “finished” with the value.

Comment: OK. Cool. Thank you. :-)