# Converting to Byte Array after reading a BLOB from SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I need to read a BLOB and store it in a byte[], before going forward with Deserializing;

Consider:

```
 //Reading the Database with DataAdapterInstance.Fill(DataSet);
     DataTable dt = DataSet.Tables[0];
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
    byte[] BinDate = Byte.Parse(row["Date"].ToString()); // convert successfully to byte[]

    }
```

I need help in this C# statement, as I am not able to convert an object type into a byte[]. Note, "Date" field in the table is a blob and not of type Date;

Help appreciated;
Soham

Comment: You may take a look at the answer I gave to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625029/how-do-i-store-and-retrieve-a-blob-from-sqlite/625485#625485

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just cast the value to a byte array:

```
byte[] binDate = (byte[])row["Date"];
```

A blob in the database maps to a byte array in .NET, so the database driver have already done that conversion for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] binDate = (byte[])row["Date"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If "Date" is a blob, it should already come out as a byte[] - not sure why you are calling `ToString()`, but `Byte.Parse` will only parse a *single* byte.