# How to map small binary objects properly in SQLite/NHibernate combo (wrong type affinity)?

Tags: sql, sqlite, nhibernate-mapping, blob, system.data.sqlite

Trying to store property of C#/.NET type `byte[]` in `SQLite`. Here is my mapping:

```
<class name="MyClass" lazy="false" table="MyTable">
   <property name="MyProperty" type ="BinaryBlob" access="property" />
</class>
```

In `SQL server` it works like a charm even without the explicit `type="BinaryBlob"` in the mapping. In `SQLite` I've tried various types' combinations between SQL `CREATE TABLE` statements and in `NHibernate` data types, but each time getting either an exception that "the mapping can't be compiled" (because of type incompatibility) or an exception that a cast from the fetched datatype to the mapping type is impossible.

The value of `MyProperty` in insert statement looks like this: `0x7C87541FD3F3EF5016E12D411900C87A6046A8E8`.

**Update**: continuing to debug `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader` - looks like no matter what SQL type is (tried `decimal`, `blob`, `unsigned big int`) - the type affinity is always `text`.

What am I doing wrong, please (either technically or in general)? Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for `text` affinity was that the data was imported into a table from ***CSV*** *(comma-separated values)* file. Switching to the ***SQL*** file with a proper `INSERT` statement solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at: [How do i store and retrieve a blob from sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625029/how-do-i-store-and-retrieve-a-blob-from-sqlite)?  There is an article on ayende.com as well here: [Lazy loading BLOBS and the like in NHibernate](http://web.archive.org/web/20100711074950/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/17/lazy-loading-blobs-and-the-like-in-nhibernate.aspx?).  These links might help push you in the right direction to see what is going on.

Comment: Oh sorry, this is an "old" question. Answering now. Thanks a lot for your help.