# How can I store the image in websql(SQLite)?

Tags: sqlite, html

I want to store images in websql(sqllite).so please provide the procedure to store images in websql.

Comment: You may [check here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

**Sqlite** has a data type called `BLOB` which is common in many DBMSes.

You can serialize the image as `byte[]` ans save it to column just like other data types.

Here is the same questoin [How do i store and retrieve a blob from sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625029/how-do-i-store-and-retrieve-a-blob-from-sqlite) asked and answered.

Comment: thanks jani for the great answer.