# Problems retrieving Images from SQLite to C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, blob

I have spent considerable time trying to retrieve images from SQLite but i have failed miserably. If some one could help me with what i am doing wrong here, that would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code i am using to retrieve a BLOB image stored in SQLite.

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.conString);
con.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT ImageFiles FROM basicconcepts WHERE id=1",con);
SQLiteDataReader reader=cmd.ExecuteReader();
byte[] imageBytes=null;
while (reader.Read())
{
  imageBytes = (System.Byte[])reader["ImageFiles"];
}
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
```

Here is the Stack Trace of the error that i am getting

```
 System.ArgumentException was caught
 Message=Parameter is not valid.
 Source=System.Drawing
 StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.frmMain.getPDF(String c_Name, Int32 pgNo) in C:\Users\Tanmay\Documents\My Projects\E-Excust\E-Excust\E-Excust\frmMain.cs:line 148
  InnerException:
```

PS the above code is inside the getPDF method.

**EDIT**

I have found a solution for my problem. The problem was, quite surprisingly the sql admin tool i was using. i would strongly recommend not to use sqlite administrator for retrieving BLOB images.
I started using SQLite Expert and everything started working fine. Could not believe i racked my head over this for one whole day
Thanks everyone for their help, specially the guys who havent answered here but helped me a lot on chat. big thanks to usernane, yas4891, SomeGuy and a few others

Comment: What type is `pictureBox1`? What format were the images when they were saved?

Comment: The images were in Jpg format. pictureBox1 because i have added a picture box on my Form

Answer (score 0):

Once you [read the binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625029/how-do-i-store-and-retrieve-a-blob-from-sqlite/625485#625485) from your database as `byte[]` you could simply:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
```

Comment: How is that going to solve my problem? it is essentially doing the same thing right? Also i checked it on chat. The guys there agreed that my code is correct