# How to store unity terrain data in sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine

I want to make an application that calls terrain data from a sqlite database into the unity in runtime. I researched a lot of sites but I have not found anything remarkable yet. Does anyone have an idea about this issue? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the Terrain Heightmap as an Image and save that as a blob in you sqlite database. See for example: [Save and Load image SQLite C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853301/save-and-load-image-sqlite-c-sharp)