# How to store list of object data in sqlite on Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to store a list of object data in SQLite on Flutter? Json data coming with API.

```
{
     "images": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "img1"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "img2"
        }
      ]
}
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_insert_query.htm, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625029/how-do-i-store-and-retrieve-a-blob-from-sqlite

Answer (score 6):

You need to serialize the list of objects before storing them using SQLite.

Firstly, you cannot store `Map` or `List` in the database directly, you need to convert `Map` or `List` to JSON `String` first, check out https://dart.dev/guides/json to learn how to use `JSON` in Dart

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

final data = {
     "images": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "img1"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "img2"
        }
      ],
};

final String dataAsJson = json.encode(data);
```

Secondly, use [Flutter sqflite package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) to create an SQLite database and create a table with the following columns:
`id` auto increment
`data` to store your data fetched from API as JSON `dataAsJson`

```dart
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

// 1. open the database first. check the documentation of `sqflite` package

// 2. insert data to the table
await db.insert(
    'images', # the name of the table
    {'data': dataAsJson}, # `data` is the column's name
);
```

Lastly, get the data from the database using `await db.query(..)`

```dart
final List<Map> maps = await db.query('images', columns: ['id', 'data']);

// now let's get the first item in the table then convert it back as it was fetched from the API.

final dataFromJsonToMap = json.decode(maps[0]);
```

If you only want to store the `images` from the API, you do not need to convert to JSON, create a table with columns `id` and `name` and insert.

```dart
await db.insert('images', {'id': 10, 'name': 'img1'});
await db.insert('images', {'id': 11, 'name': 'img2'});
```

Comment: at 2 point when passing json value then get it show error which is  Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(table class_time_table has no column named data (Sqlite code
 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO class_time_table (data) VALUES (?), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)) sql 'INSERT OR REPLACE IN
TO class_time_table (data) VALUES (?)' args [[{"class_name":"9TH","section_name":"A","subject_n...]

Comment: The error says there is no column named `data` in the table `class_time_table`. Add the mentioned column then try again.

Comment: i already add it but  still facing the  problem here is code  db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE time_table(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, data TEXT,)'
      );

Comment: Updated code
db.execute( 'CREATE TABLE class_time_table(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, data TEXT,)' )

Comment: If the previous sqlite database file is still existing, you need to delete it first, create a new database with a new filename, or only add the missing column `data` using `db.execute('ALTER TABLE ..')` see https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-alter-table

Comment: @HasanAlyazidi suppose If I want to change name "img2" to "img5" , then how to update it using sqfLite Update query

Comment: @Deepak Please create a new question and inform me to reply.