Putting Image file into SQLite Blob field with VB.Net
I have been attempting to put an image file into an SQLite blob field.
The code runs as I would expect but nothing is added to the table. If I try and run the same code again it errors with the following: "constraint failed UNIQUE constraint failed: PHOTO.Award_No".
If I change the Award_No in the code then it appears to run correctly again but still nothing is added to the table.
My code is:
Private Sub btnProcessSingle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcessSingle.Click
    Dim sqlite_cmd As New SQLiteCommand
    Dim sqlite_conn As New SQLiteConnection("DataSource=" & Application.StartupPath & "Database1.db;Version=3")
    Dim data() As Byte

    data = File.ReadAllBytes(txtFileName.Text)

    sqlite_conn.Open()
    sqlite_cmd.Connection = sqlite_conn

    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PHOTO(Award_No, Photo) VALUES('2022-001', @img)"
    sqlite_cmd.Prepare()

    sqlite_cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", DbType.Binary, data.Length)
    sqlite_cmd.Parameters("@img").Value = data

    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    sqlite_conn.Close()

    txtFileName.Text = ""

End Sub


If you're told that the ID is already present then obviously the data was added to the table. The problem is almost certainly you not looking in the right place for said data. The first thing you should be doing is checking the value returned by ExecuteNonQuery. If that is anything other than zero, data was saved to the database.

How EXACTLY does this database file end up in your program folder? With file-based databases, the process is often that you add a source data file to your project and then that gets copied to the output folder with the EXE when you build. The advantage of that is that you keep your source database clean and you can test on the copy and mess with its data as much as you like. If you look for changes in the source file though, you obviously won't see them, because they were made to the copy in the output folder.

Also, if you use the process specified above, the default is for the source file to be copied to the output folder every time you build. This means that if you run your app, make changes to data, stop the app, make code changes and run the app again, your data changes will be lost because the source file will be copied over the working file again. You should select the data file in the Solution Explorer and set Copy to Output Directory to Copy if Newer. That way, the source file is only copied when you make changes to it directly or you delete the working file.

By the way, I'm not 100% sure that this is supported by that SQLite provider but, if it is, you should use this connection string instead: "DataSource=|DataDirectory|\Database1.db;Version=3". The biggest advantage of that format is that it can be stored in a config file or the like and does not need code executed at run time to generate it. If you are going to do it the way you are, you should not use string concatenation to build file and folder paths: $"DataSource={Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Database1.db")};Version=3". Path.Combine` will always use correct delimiters.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625029/how-do-i-store-and-retrieve-a-blob-from-sqlite
